# Fixtures in raw Python?

Tags: django, django-fixtures

Is there a way to have fixtures in raw Python to, for example, create initial data from external files? I have fixtures in JSON presently, and it might actually be more effective to migrate them to a kind of CSV file and have Python parse these and insert them. Is there a way to do this in Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catch the `post_syncdb` signal and do your work in the handler.

Comment: I can't have an `initial_data.py` file or something like that? Is there a way to do this without involving signals?

Comment: Django only supports [XML, YAML, JSON, or SQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/) as initial data.

Comment: Ok, great. I thought I had heard that they supported Python fixtures, but I guess this works too :)

Answer (score 1):

I just released library for exactly this purposes https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django_pyfixture/

You'll get `manage.py loaddata_py <fixturename>` for console API and `py_fixtures = [<list of fixtures>]` for your tests.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django_pyfixture/